# Over which types of ground surfaces do we have more updraught?

Tags: turbulence, meteorology

When a light airplane is flying around 2000-3000 ft AGL, over which places will it deal with updraught more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about thermals from the sun heating the ground, it depends on the surface's solar absorption/release characteristics, and this has a lot to do with moisture content, variations in the surface composition and the air mass's stability.

The vast majority of the sun's energy that reaches earth's surface is absorbed into the air by conduction and transported up by convection, or, absorbed into water vapour via evaporation. This means that where water is present, it tends to slow the release of energy by conduction.

The result is you get strong thermal updrafts from dry surfaces that tend to absorb and release energy quickly. Large asphalt and concrete surfaces, rocky areas, dry fields with minimal foliage.  Wetter surfraces, lakes, wet fields, swampy land, wherever there is higher moisture, tend to produce weaker thermals that start and stop later in the day, due to the heat sink and storage effect of the moisture.

The other big variable is the stability of the air itself, a function of its lapse rate (temperature change with pressure). Unstable air has a higher lapse rate is more easily encouraged to start rising when energy is added.

This is all why the worst days for unpleasant bumpiness are sunny, dry weather days over dry terrain (deserts are the worst); good for glider pilots (if the wind isn't too strong), bad for power pilots wanting a smooth ride.

I prefer to fly my power plane outside of the strongest solar heating periods because of this (for soaring, the opposite). Early morning or later afternoon if the sun is out, or during overcast weather.

If the winds are strong, mechanical turbulence from air flowing over contours like ridges becomes a factor, even on overcast days where thermal activity is minimal. So at those altitudes expect a rougher ride over hilly terrain for a few thousand feet above the surface, depending on how hilly it is and how strong the wind is, even if it's overcast or too early in the day for thermals.

If you're taking someone for a ride in a power plane in sunny weather, try to arrange it for morning before 9 or 10 am, or in the early evening, say after 5 pm. With light winds as well to minimize mechanical turbulence.